# Facebook API - Pages - Get names of subscribers

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get the names of the subscribers of my facebook Page (I want to thank them and develop a single page website who mention each of them).

I use jQuery?

I have not find anything in the doc.

Comment: this question is just too broad but yes you can do it with jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to get the fans of a Facebook Page. If you mean the followers of your User profile, that is not possible either. You should actually treat them as if they would be anonymous.

Btw, you would not be allowed to put them on an external website without their permission anyway.